# Is it possible to replace executable in a container in a POD while it's running?

Tags: go, kubernetes, containers, workflow

I'm developing a Go executable on Ubuntu and running a kubernetes cluster in minikube.  The pod+container that's running in minikube is based on Ubuntu, and I just want to replace the executable in the container.  More or less bypassing the need to remake the container because executable is the only thing that needs to change.  When my changes are 'ready' I plan to remake the image the container is based on, etc., but that's down the road.

I'm looking to iterate a bit quicker really.

Is this possible?  Is there a better way?

Comment: The kubernetes way to do this would be using a Deployment instead and updating the deployment. That way you won't have a downtime while the pod is replaced.
You can probably find a way to replace the executable in a pod depending on your docker setup but I believe that's not a good way to go forward in my oppinion and not very "kubernetes like".
What is the issue with your current workflow? Replacing the pod should only take a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For development purposes ONLY (quite hacky solution), you can have your Ubuntu-Go container running `tail -f /dev/null` to keep it from finishing, and use a `hostPath` to mount the path containing your executable to your container. You can run your Go application by running a `kubectl exec` and any changes you make to your application on your host will be reflected in the container. You can restart the application, again with `kubectl exec` whenever the executable is updated.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/host_folder_mount.md) is a good readme on how to use minikube's hostPath.

REMEMBER IN PRODUCTION to rebuild your container with the correct binary, define the correct entrypoint, and fix your deployment/pod definition to exclude the hostPath.

Answer (score 0):

With “kubectl edit deployment” you can change the image of a specified container in a pod. When you close the modified deployment yaml file, the pod is stopped and restarted.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33074257)